# FreeBSD Swift Installation Errors

Tags: python, freebsd, llvm

I am attempting to:

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/swift/ ; make install clean
```

I have been plagued by llvm38 errors throughout the process, but what I can't figure out is this:

> > llvm38-3.8.1 depends on package: py34-enum34>0 - not found

I have three questions:

1. What does the >0 mean? (I have not seen this before)
2. Where is py34-enum34? py27-enum34-1.1.6 is installed (via pkg)
3. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are using Python 2.7, hence you installed the [backported enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34). If this is correct, then most likely you are seeing a conflict between the packages `Enum` and `enum34`. You may try uninstalling `Enum` by means of

```
pip uninstall Enum
```

I have just tried this, and what does **not** work with packages installed, works perfectly without `Enum`.

EDIT:

apologies for not having been clear. What I am suggesting is that you uninstall the current version of Enum you have installed (py27-enum34) and install instead py34-enum34 from my first link. A *backported* package differs from a *non*-backported package.

Comment: Running pip3 uninstall Enum states that Enum is not installed. py27-enum34 was installed already when I searched the system for enum34.

Comment: @BrandonBradley Pls. read my Edit.